# Visual Studio 2015 website development android emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm developing a website that I will soon port to Android, Windows 10, and iOS. I'm using an HTML/CSS/Javascript combo and I started the project in Visual Studio 2015 as a new website.

I am able to test the site using all of my installed browsers and Windows Phone 8.1 (the Windows 10 emulators open but won't debug for some reason). I would like to be able to test my site on an Android emulator while in Visual Studio. I can launch a number of Android emulators outside of Visual Studio just fine by launching "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" through the Start menu, but I cannot figure out how to use these for debugging. There is no Android emulator option in the "Browse with" menu and I don't exactly know how to add one.

I know the emulators are probably more for developing actual Android applications but if this is possible I would like to do it to test for mobile browser quirks. Thanks!!

Comment: You need to install a browser in the emulator, then browse to a URL.

Comment: The Android emulator came with a default browser but I don't know how to get it to access my file system to test my work. My desktop browsers say "localhost" followed by a 5-digit number but plugging that in to the Android browser did nothing. Ideas?

Comment: You need to connect to your host machine's IP address on that port.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support, SLaks. Sorry to say that I'm entirely sure how follow your suggestion. I took my ip address and the port number and combined them like this: ##.##.###.##:64833  -  I put that in the android browser address bar but get nothing. Am I following your suggestion correctly? Thanks!

Comment: That might be because your firewall is blocking it.

Comment: I turned off the firewall and still had no luck. http://10.0.2.2:64833 brings up the "Webpage not available" "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT" message.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for debugging hybrid apps (And especifically those on mobile devices) is to use a tool like VorlonJS. Here's a [video + walkthrough](http://www.davevoyles.com/debugging-web-apps-with-vorlon-js/) on how to use it.

**What is it?**

The fine folks on the TED team at Microsoft introduced VorlonJS during //BUILD last week. Vorlon is an open source, extensible, platform-agnostic tool for remotely debugging and testing your JavaScript. Powered by node.js and socket.io.

I put together a brief video tutorial on how to set up Vorlon and have it debug not only web applications running in desktop browsers, but also mobile ones. In this particular case, I cover Firefox and Chrome on the desktop, and IE 11 on a Windows Phone simulator.

To get started, you simply install run Vorlon from the Node Package Manager (NPM) with the following command:

```
npm i -g vorlon
```

Then call Vorlon from NPM to spin up an express server and you are ready to debug!

```
Vorlon
```

Add the following JavaScipt to any web app you want to debug, and Vorlon will communicate with it through the Vorlon express server you started in the previous step.

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/vorlon.js"></script>
```

In my browser, I navigate to http://localhost:1337/ and I can see Vorlon running, and in a second tab, I nagivate to the address of the application I am running from local host and see that the two are connected!

Comment: Looks like there's an issue on your video+walkthrough link.

Comment: Sorry @RemiDespres-Smyth, that site should work, but it is a bit slow to respond at times. Here is an alternate link: https://github.com/DaveVoyles/VorlonJSDemoSite